# Update a question or post a new question?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions, updating-questions

The question I posted earlier wasn't clear and I was myself un-aware of the exact problem so I didn't get any responses. After a while I was able to figure out the problem (but still looking for a solution) so I edited the question (it's almost a different question now) and I think the updated question makes much more sense for someone who could answer it.

This is the question:

[Can't see a file in Windows written by an android app on sd-card unless I “Force Close” the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7391432/cant-see-a-file-in-windows-written-by-an-android-app-on-sd-card-unless-i-force)

But, I'm not sure whether updating a question is able to attract people's attention again. So, is it better to post a new one (and may be delete the old one?)

Comment: When you edit a question, it bumps it up the active list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> But, I'm not sure whether updating a question is able to attract people's attention

Editing a question bumps up the question on the homepage & tag pages, so it is more or less similar to the same state as a new question.

> So, is it better to post a new one (and may be delete the old one?)

If there's a significant deviation, then it's better to start afresh & post a new question.

---

In your case, it's a new question altogether. I've edited out the "new" question. Better to post it as a new one.

Answer (score 5):

When you edit an old question, it is bumped up in the front page, and everybody see it again.

Deleting a question somebody has already answered is something I would avoid, when possible; if you keep doing it, users would be discouraged to answer your questions, as they would be afraid you are going to delete the answer. It is not always possible to delete a question with answers, thought.

Keeping to change the question when there are already answers is something I would avoid too. You should post a question when it's already clear what the problem is; changing the question basing on what reported in the answers has the effect of invalidating the given answers.
SE sites are not thought for a continuous feedback between who asks the question and who answers such as in:

1. I ask a question.
2. You answer my question.
3. I change my question.
4. You change your answer.
5. Repeat from 3.